# Can a function be called within its own definition?

Tags: php, function

I am new to PHP.

I downloaded a programme in which the `function.php` file contains:

```php
function registerglobal() {

    $args = func_get_args();

    while (list(,$key) = each ($args)), {   
        if (isset($_GET[$key])) $value = $_GET[$key];
        if (isset($_POST[$key])) $value = $_POST[$key];
        if (isset($_FILES[$key])) $value = $_FILES[$key];

        if (isset($value)) {
            if (!ini_get ('magic_quotes_gpc')) {
                if (!is_array($value))
                    $value = addslashes($value);
                else
                    $value = slasharray($value);
            }

            $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
            unset($value);
        }
    }
}

function slasharray ($a) { 
    while (list($k,$v) = each($a)) {
        if (!is_array($v))
            $a[$k] = addslashes($v);
        else
            $a[$k] = slasharray($v);
    }
    reset ($a);
    return ($a);
}
```

1. Under `function registerglobal()` we have `while (list(,$key) = each ($args)), {`. Is the comma in `(,$key)` correct?
2. Since `function slasharray()` is called in the previous `function
   registerglobals()` I think `slasharray()` should be defined first. Am I wrong?
3. Why `slasharray($v)` under `function slasharray()`? Has `function slasharray()` been assigned a specific, identifiable task to perform?  Hence my original question: **can one call a function within its own definition?**

Comment: *"can one call a function within itself"* – Yes. That's called *recursion*. There's no limit of what you can call from where. A function call is just a function call, it doesn't matter where it's from. What the rest of the question is about I honestly don't know, TL;DR.

Comment: _" I think slasharray() should be defined first."_  - it doesn't matter which function you define first.

Comment: @deceze: Thanks. Just that I am trying to understand the code. I type in correct Username and Password on Login page and I keep getting Invalid Login. When I set error_reporting to (E_ALL) I get notices of undefined variables and indexes all over the login page and I am going all over the programme to understand why.

Comment: But then look at the code again and how does slasharray($v) know what to do if its instructions are still being issued? If I call a function it should have a function first right? Else I am just wasting time right?

Comment: «*how does slasharray($v) know what to do if its instructions are still being issued*» — In simple terms by the time php gets to execute it (in execution pharse), it is already fully defined in the compilation phase.

Comment: @weirdan. Okay. Thanks.

Comment: @weirdan. Thanks. I hope I can understand your explanation  some time soon. The code for slasharray($a) just seems to me for now to be syntaxically correct but logically fatal; like it would lead me into an indefinite loop like a mirror in a mirror. If you understood how I see it perhaps you might better be able to lead me out of my darkness into the light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear up the confusion, let's see how php compiles a function call:

```
<?php
 strpos("a", "b");
```

Is compiled into this

```
line # * E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   INIT_FCALL                                               'strpos'
         1        SEND_VAL                                                 'a'
         2        SEND_VAL                                                 'b'
         3        DO_ICALL                                                 
         4      > RETURN                                                   1
```

https://3v4l.org/0pOeh/vld#output

And a call to a function that doesn't exist:

```
<?php
non_existant_function("a");
```

is compiled into this

```
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3     0  E >   INIT_FCALL_BY_NAME                                       'non_existant_function'
         1        SEND_VAL_EX                                              'a'
         2        DO_FCALL                                      0          
         3      > RETURN                                                   1
```

https://3v4l.org/YEDFB/vld#output

As you can see, in either case function name is stored in bytecode operands. This function name is looked up in a global function table *at the time the call is executed* (NB: *and no earlier then that*). No addresses are taken, no argument type and count is validated at compilation phase (unlike languages like C).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will take some time to digest this. I am sure it would help one way or the other.